# How can I use JSON.parse in nunjucks

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

i am get data in `mongodb` and `express` return occurs without errors but I wanted to use `JSON.parse` in the final results of my `.find` see below how I'm trying to do this

```
  app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    var credentialClient = {
      expire_at: false,
      __v: false,
      _id: false
    };

    rememberMe.find({ username: "test-login" }, credentialClient, function (err, credentialInfo) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.render("login.html", {
          usernameClient: JSON.parse(credentialInfo)
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Without `JSON.parse` the final rendering stays that way in my `login.html`

```
{ username: 'test-login' }
```

The final results appear in `login.html`

```
<p class="center-align black-text" id="preFinalCredentialClient">{{ usernameClient }}</p>
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: i think that `credentialInfo ` (the result from mongo.find()) is already json format. you don't need to call `JSON.parse()`

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: @AlongkornChetasumon he is already in `json` but at the time of rendering in `{{ usernameClient }}` data return comes all badly formatted and messy in my `<p class="black-text center-align">{{ usernameClient }}</p>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`credentialInfo` is already JS object, no need to `parse` it.

```
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    var credentialClient = {
      expire_at: false,
      __v: false,
      _id: false
    };

    rememberMe.find({ username: "test-login" },
         credentialClient, function (err, credentialInfo) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.render("login.html", {
          usernameClient: credentialInfo
        });
      }
    });
  });

<p class="center-align black-text" id="preFinalCredentialClient">{{ usernameClient.username }}</p>
```

On the client, you can then access the properties of `usernameClient`.

Answer (score 2):

I hope below code will work for you. In below example, I have kept static json data. In your case you can store json data in any variable and render

index.nunjucks passing that variable.

```
var express = require( 'express' ) ;

var nunjucks = require( 'nunjucks' ) ;

var app = express() ;

app.get( '/', function( req, res )

 {

var jsondata = 

{

firstName: "Rakesh",
lastName: "Barani"

};

return res.render('index.njk', {data:jsondata}) ;

res.render('index.njk', {data: jsondata})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It already returns JSON response so 
You can use this:

```
res.render("login.html", {
   usernameClient: credentialInfo.username
});
```

Comment: until `usernameClient: credentialInfo` it renders but when adding `username` in `usernameClient` it does not render on the front end

Comment: Then just pass this :  usernameClient: credentialInfo